"How to Dockerize React, Spring Boot, and Android App Projects with Environment variable access only?"
I currently Have 3 projects: React frontend, Springboot backend, and Android APK app.
I want to know how to structure the DockerFile, .env, and docker-compose files for each. When I Dockerize the whole system (make an IMG), whoever I give it to will only have edit access for the environment variables.
NOTES:

The project will be deployed using either AWS or Google Cloud.
The Android app will be deployed using Androids Internal App Sharing or Managed Google Play.
All 3 projects are in the same root folder.
All 3 projects are submodules of the rootfolder.
rootfolder is a git repo.

folder structure is as follows:
RootFolder -
          |
          |
          - frontend
          - backend
          - Android app

Or is there another way to achieve this result that might be easier? As I don't want people to be able to access the raw code but are allowed to manipulate the enviroment variables values however they want.
SIDE QUESTION
Can someone also explain the best way to set up a PostgreSQL database in application.properties/docker-compose file for the spring boot backend? like the best settings for heavy daily traffic. Or just some recommendations.
I tried creating separate DockerFiles, and .env files for each with the exception of the Android app because I have no idea where to start with that one. then create a basic docker-compose file in the root folder.
But I feel like I'm not only doing this wrong but inefficient.
